# Custom Meta Data is not being saved

Tags: metabox, post-meta, custom-field

I have created a custom meta box using following link in wordpress 3.0:
http://farinspace.com/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-meta-box/

I am using same code and custom meta data is not being saved. I get blank textbox in custom meta box each time.

Please let me know what to do.

Comment: Please post your code. We can't really do anything if we can't see what you are doing, or doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As you may have noticed from the notes at the top of that [page](http://farinspace.com/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-meta-box/), you may want to consider using [WPAlchemy Meta Box](http://farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/) for creating your meta boxes instead as it would make your dev a lot easier.